# LTE questions (subcarriers and cyclic prefix)

Tags: digital-communications

Assume we have transmission bandwidth of 10 MHz, in this case the total number of subcarriers (FFT size) present is 1024. According to LTE standards, 600 out of 1024 subcarriers are data subcarriers.

data subcarriers= total number of subcarriers- pilot/null subcarriers

Moreover, 0.07 % of 1024 are used as Cyclic Prefix extension

1) Is it correct that we have 1024-600 are therefore unused subcarriers?
(where 600 = total number of Resource Blocks (RB) * number of subcarriers/RB = 50*12)

2) An OFDM symbol is made up of data part and CP part. Is it correct to say that the number of QAM symbols for each OFDM symbol is then 600 (equal to number of data subcarriers) and the number of CP symbols are 72? How is the actual transmission over the subcarriers taking place. For example in downlink, does the transmitter allocate a certain number of subcarriers over which it transmits?

I hope I can get some feedback! Thanks

Comment: What exactly are "Cyclic Prefix subcarriers"? The CP is inserted in time domain. Do you have a reference for this type of subcarriers in LTE?

Comment: Actually I got this from a book called Fundamentals of LTE, in that book some constant G defined as Guard fraction is 0.07% of 2048 for CP. So I thought these are for the CP subcarriers. @Deve

Comment: Does the book mention "CP subcarriers"? I'm sure the "guard fraction" means the ratio of guard interval and OFDM symbol length.

Comment: I see your point, I will edit the question accordingly so as to not confuse people. By guard interval do you mean Cyclic Prefix?@Deve

Comment: Yes, the guard interval is usually implemented by a cyclic prefix.

Comment: Do you have an idea, why the 1024-900 subcarriers are unused?@Deve

Comment: Yes, this is done for oversampling. Some subcarriers are unused to faciliate anti-aliasing filtering at the receiver. You mention 600 and 900 data subcarriers in your question. Which number is correct?

Comment: 600 are the data subcarriers. However 900 are the total available resource blocks for a 10 MHz system. which is equal to 75 * 12, 75 being the total number of resource blocks and 12 being the number of subcarriers in one resource block.

Comment: I would have thought that the unused subcarriers are those at the left and right of the bandwidth and are unused for interference purposes.

Comment: That's right, the margins of the transmit band are unused. Reducing cross-band interference is one reason for doing that, the anti-aliasing filter is another. Maybe you should mention in you question that it refers to the LTE downlink (if it does), because the uplink is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The FFT size in LTE is defined as 2^(nextpow2(Nsubcarriers/2)+1) or the nearest power of two that is also higher than the number of subcarriers for a given bandwidth. For the 10 Mhz case, for example, this means that 424 FFT bins(1024-600) are zero padded apart including the DC bin. The usual practice is to zero pad the central 423+DC bins and use the rest for filling the data so that you get a continous spectrum of 10 MHz around DC. You can also fill the central 600 FFT bins with data and do a fftshift. See table 1 in [this](http://www.tsiwireless.com/docs/whitepapers/LTE%20in%20a%20Nutshell%20-%20Physical%20Layer.pdf) document.
2. Yes. Each Resource Element(i.e.1 subcarrier and 1 OFDM system in the Time- Frequency Grid) has one QAM Symbol in shared channel.

Check out [this](http://niviuk.free.fr/lte_resource_grid.html) visualization to get a better clarity about the LTE resource grid. The resource is allocated both in time and frequency domain and in the case of Multi User MIMO(MU-MIMO) transmission mode, spatial resource allocation of resource elements to different user equipment in the downlink also take place. To keep things simple, let's just focus on a single-antennae transmission. The following diagram will give you a better idea of the whole transmission process.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. Shouldn't the output of the FFT inverse operation be also parallel symbols? As I see in this figure its a serial output of symbols? Also does this figure shown, where is the actual allocation of resource elements taking place to send the QAM symbols?

Comment: The output of IFFT is a complex sinusoidal waveform. You can see the real and imaginary parts that are multiplied by sin and cosine components of the carrier. This waveform is transmitter at a sampling rate commensurate to the bandwidth (Fs=15.34 Mhz for BW of 10 MHz) as shown in table 3.1.1-1 in [this](http://www.freescale.com/files/wireless_comm/doc/white_paper/3GPPEVOLUTIONWP.pdf) document.

Comment: Thank you again, so do you mean to say that the output of the IFFT is not serial symbols but actually a complex waveform? then how come we have a digital to analog converter after the inverse FFT? I thought the inverse FFT would transform the frequency domain symbols into time domain symbols and thats it?

Comment: I have been using this document http://www.freescale.com/files/wireless_comm/doc/white_paper/3GPPEVOLUTIONWP.pdf, can you please check page 13. It seems to be that the two diagrams are not quite the same

Comment: Good answer, but you say "that 1024-423 FFT bins are zero padded". Shouldn't it be the other way round, namely that 423 bins are zero-padded and 1024-423=601 are used for payload data?

Comment: @Tyrone The (hardware) IFFT output is indeed parallel and has to be serialized before it can be converted to an analog signal. I think the figure is just simplified in this regard.

Comment: @Deve Edited the answer. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: @Tyrone In page 13 of that document, what you are seeing is the block diagram of Single Carrier-FDMA(SC-FDMA) which is the modulation technique used by the end-user device. OFDM is only used by the LTE eNB(base station). The common areas between OFDM and SC-FDMA highlighted in the document is the same as figure in the above answer, except for the Single carrier constellation mapping block. The DAC and later components comes in the RF Front End. Recall that FFT decomposes a waveform into NFFT frequency components whereas IFFT is the inverse operation which produces a composite waveform.

Comment: thanks i was just trying to highlight from thw figure that i mentioned the fact that the output of the ifft is parallel and not serial...

Comment: @Tyrone Yes, thats correct. The radix structure of IFFT block has parallel input and parallel output.

Comment: @Deve can you please explain why you put hardware in paranthesis when describing the ifft output. Does a software ifft not behave same?

Comment: @Tyrone I think he is referring to shift registers in hardware buffers into which IFFT output is pushed before further processing. In software we work with arrays, but the underlying logic is the same.

Comment: @Tyrone Exactly. In software, the concept of parallel and serial data streams doesn't make a lot of sense. While the IFFT could in principle be parallelized in software using several cores, this is rarely done.